# Node stoichiometry in LPG and RDF graphs

Tags: sparql, rdf, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have some background in RDF, but am currently working on building a Labeled Property Graph (LPG) in Gremlin. I have a doubt regarding redundant links in LPGs.

Say I want to represent the fact that Bag1 contains a blue bead and a red bead. In RDF I could do:

```
:Bag1 :contains :Blue_bead .
:Bag1 :contains :Red_bead .
```

This becomes a problem if I want to represent that Bag2 contains *two* blue beads, since that would simply repeat the exact same triple twice:

```
:Bag2 :contains :Blue_bead .
:Bag2 :contains :Blue_bead .
```

One way I've seen this solved (in the Biopax ontology) for RDF is to represent the stoichiometry like so (0 blue; 3 red):

```
:Bag3 :component :Blue_bead .
      :componentStoichiometry :Stoichiometry1 .
:Stoichiometry1 :stoichiometricCoefficient "0" ;
                :physicalEntity :Blue_bead .
:Bag3 :component :Red_bead .
      :componentStoichiometry :Stoichiometry2 .
:Stoichiometry2 :stoichiometricCoefficient "3" ;
                :physicalEntity :Red_bead .
```

Or specifically for Complex/PhysicalEntity in Biopax rather than Bag/bead:
[image: BioPax complex stoichiometry]

**Question**
In the case of LPGs, would I need to use a similar representation for stoichiometry, or is there a more straightforward way? Since all edges are uniquely labeled, can I represent a bag containing 3 blue beads by simply linking the bag node to the blue bead with three edges? Or will that not suit the purpose?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the BioPax example, you may have some syntax errors there. About RDF, I would say that you could use RDF containers or collections, since using a single containment relation (`:contains`) does not work.

Comment: For LPG, you could do as you suggest, or use a container datatype (list or set) as a property value.

Comment: Added a figure from the Biopax documentation for visualization. Basically it requires a unique Stoichiometry node for every Complex/PhysicalEntity pair. It is a rather convoluted way of representing stoichiometry in RDF, but it avoids the use of collections or containers.
Anyway, sounds like this should be straightforward in LPG then. Thanks!

Comment: In RDF you could also do `:Bag1 :contains [a :Stoichiometry; :color :Blue]` which would be a new node for every member of a bag. You could even do subclasses of `:Stoichiometry` called `:BlueBall`, etc., and then do `:Bag1 :contains [a :BlueBall]` . ;-)